# Dynamic and type-safe function-parameters using the yargs api

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, yargs

I want to share a coding challenge with you and hope someone also feels attracted to this challenge, and can help, because it demands some 'advanced' Typescript skills :)
First of all some basic Javascript, to make clear what I want to do:

```
// create a custom Task using a custom, configurable creator function
// 'createTask' should be a higher-order function returning the actual task function
const customTask = createTask( /* Some configuration parameters should go here */); 

// now we should be able to execute the task with some custom arguments
const result = customTask( { foo: true} );
```

The challange is to implement the `createTask` function so that...

1. you can provide the actual implementation of the task via a `callback` parameter to the `createTask` function
2. all custom arguments should be configurable using the awesome api from the [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) package
3. the typescript compiler should warn you if you execute the task with wrong parameters

#### Revision 1 - without type checking

Let's ignore the type checking issue for now.
So in plain javascript it should be something like this:

```
  function createTask(callback, parameterConfiguration) {
    return function(customArgs) {
      // TODO: make sure that only valid args are passed to the callback. (using parameterConfiguration)
      // execute the task with custom arguments
      return callback(customArgs);
    };
  }
  
  // We should be able to use the yargs api to configure which parameters our task should have:
  const parameterConfiguration = require('yargs').option('foo', { type: 'boolean' });
  
  // now we create our task with:
  const customTaskWithFoo = createTask(callback, parameterConfiguration);
  
  // callback function which does the actual meaningful work
  function callback(customArgsWithFoo) {
    const { foo } = customArgsWithFoo;
    console.log('executing with args:', { foo });
  }
  
  // later we should be able to execute the task with values for all configured parameters:
  customTaskWithFoo({ foo: true });
```

#### Revision 2 - basic type checking

Now lets write this with typescript:

```
import { Argv } from 'yargs'

export type CustomTask<Params, Return> = (args: Params) => Return

export type CustomTaskCallback<Params, Return> = (args: Params) => Return

export function createTask<Params, Return>(callback: CustomTaskCallback<Params, Return>, parameterConfiguration: Argv<Params>): CustomTask<Params, Return> {
   return function(customArgs: Params) {

        const argsFromYargs = parameterConfiguration.argv
   
        const actualArgs = {
          ...argsFromYargs,
          ...customArgs
        }

        return callback(actualArgs)
    }
}

const customTaskWithFoo = createTask(callback, require('yargs').option('foo', { type: 'boolean' }))

// callback function which does the actual meaningful work
function callback(customArgsWithFoo): void {
  const { foo } = customArgsWithFoo
  console.log('executing with args:', { foo })
}

// execute the task. Works as expected. No compiler errors  
customTaskWithFoo({ foo: false })

// Now this should be permitted by the typescript compiler,
// because the `foo` parameter was configured to be a `boolean`
// using the yargs api before with `.option('foo', { type: 'boolean' })`
// Unfortunately this is actually not rejected by the compiler.
customTaskWithFoo({ foo: 'string-value' })
```

Now to make this work as expected I guess I need to use some more sophisticated typescript magic.

#### Revision 3 - Almost perfect, but with redundant type information

I think I'm already close, because it works when I explicitly provide the Type for the `customTask` variable:

```
// customTask with explicit type:
let customTask: CustomTask< {foo:boolean}, void>
customTask = createTask(callback, require('yargs').option('foo', { type: 'boolean' }))

// now this is rejected as expected:
customTask({ foo: 'string-value' })
```

I'm just not satisfied with having to write the type of `foo` at 2 places: fist in the variable declaration `let customTask: CustomTask<{**foo:boolean**}, void>` and a second time at the yargs api call `.option( 'foo', { **type: 'boolean'** } )`

I believe there are some advanced typescript features that allow the compiler to infer the type of the `customTask` automatically from the api call of yargs.
I hope someone can help :)

Thanks!

Comment: This comment about currying from the docs likely applies: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#point-free-programming

Comment: @RandyCasburn 
Ah, you mean this quote: ` In TypeScript, type inference often fails for point-free programs, so you’ll end up specifying type parameters ...` Hmm, ...but I still have hope ^^.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have hope for your too! If it were a job task it would not be a big deal, but as a challenge, well its a challenge.